# Need to play two audio streams at the same time

Tags: audio

I set up a darkice server using raspberry pis in my kid's rooms as baby monitors.  They steam to a website m3u file so VLC and to be the answer.  I'm trying to accomplish 1 of 2 things.

A.) Play both streams simultaneously... This seems impossible.

Or

B). Stream each to different speakers at the same time.  I have an external USB speaker, a USB sound card or a Bluetooth speaker to choose from.

Thanks!

Comment: Open VLC 2 times and play 1 stream on each VLC?

Comment: Doesn't work as the sound card can only handle one at a time